# how to open a $mdDialog inside another $mdDialog without exit the first one?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I just want to know how can I open an mdDialog inside another mdDialog without exit the first one, because when I do so, it always hide the first one.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is impossible to open multiple dialogs at the same time.

According to [this issue thread](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/698) in github, there is no precise version that this is scheduled to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material spec recommends not to do it. Here is the link  [Dialogs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior)

```
Dialogs should avoid:

Opening dialogs from within a dialog Containing scrolling content Full-screen dialog exception

Full-screen dialogs may open additional dialogs, such as pickers, because their design accommodates additional layers of material without significantly increasing the app’s perceived z-depth or visual noise.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 1.3 or higher version then use `multiple:true` in your inner dialog. It works for me. I am opening date picker dialog box in md-dialog.